# EIP20 and ERC20 not compatiable in token contract?

Tags: ico

I am issuing a token coin via ERC20 and I also include a crowd sale within this contract? 
ie start time
   end time
   bonus period
   total supply
?  8 or 18 public decimals
? I got confused with the EIP20 interface,,,,,,,,,,,,,learning still, thank you

Comment: You should clarify what are you asking, that will increase your chances of getting help.

Comment: your are right sorry for not being specific Anne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EIP is an improvement proposal and not something you should implement.

ERC is the standard that most people use for compatibility purposes. If you are launching a token, you should use this.

Comment: thank you too much late night study. I am sure its 18 decimals.

Comment: @ABonney The decimals you choose does not break the standard. 18 is common, but you can choose any decimal size below 18 and it’ll be perfectly valid.

Comment: thanks, I wrote a smart contract and few issues have been flag  up. I want to do a ICO coin listing for my Company.